# Java GUI menu bar not showing

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Any idea why the menu bar `menuBar`  is not showing? everything looks fine to me.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class mySticky extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    //weStart!

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sticky Note");
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu noteMenu = new JMenu("Note");
    JMenuItem newNote = new JMenuItem("New Note");
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As");
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");

    //Constructor

    public mySticky(){

        setSize(400,300);
        setLocation(500,250);
        setTitle("Sticky Note");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        menuBar.add(noteMenu);

        noteMenu.add(newNote);
        noteMenu.add(open);
        noteMenu.add(saveAs);
        noteMenu.add(save);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);            
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){           

    }


    public static void main (String [] args ){

        mySticky sticky = new mySticky ();
        sticky.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: for posting http://sscce.org/ +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add the menubar to `frame`, which is never added to any UI. Replace

```
frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

by

```
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

and your menubar will become visible. Or you should add `frame` to the UI as well. Not sure what you tried to achieve.

And you should wrap the code of your main method in a `Runnable` and execute it on the EDT (for example using `EventQueue.invokeLater`)

Comment: Totally correct. I got it now.  I'm afraid I don't know what is `EventQueue.invokeLater`?

Comment: All Swing operations should be performed on a special Thread. You can perform those operations on that thread by using the methods in the EventQueue class, for example [EventQueue.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) . See the [Swing Concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar)`, try `this.setJMenuBar(menuBar)` in your constructor.